# jQuery lookup from databound checklist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, dynamics-crm

My MSCRM 2015 online solution uses a 3rd party tool to build a checkbox list from `N:N` dynamically and this is then published in another Iframe, I was wandering if I could use `jQuery` to test if any of these checkboxes are checked in `JavaScript`

Problem though if you look at the `html` these inputs don't have id's or names I can use to reference them with something like ...

```
var checkboxValues = [];
$('input[name=checboxset_ava_incident_ava_affectedcountry]:checked').map(function() {
        checkboxValues.push($(this).val());
```

Here is an example of how the `html` get build:

[image: Html of the generated Checkbox Group]

hope the sizing is ok to read But what I want you to see is the `<input>` tag's properties:

```
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="id: Id, checked: Value, title: Name, enable: $parent.GetIsEnabled()">
```

Comment: Thanks @palpatim - and so I learn, this is the result I wanted: jsfiddle.net/ho1xcrzc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find selected checkboxes, radio buttons or select elements, look at the [jQuery `:checked` selector](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/), as in

```
$(':checked')...
```

If you want checkboxes, use the `type` attribute in your selector, as in

```
$('input[type=checkbox]')...
```

or combine them, to find only checked checkboxes (i.e., to ensure that you don't pick up any radio buttons or select elements):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked')...
```

**DEMO**

```js
var findChecked = function() {
  var checked_values = [];
  var $checkedBoxes = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
  console.log('$checkedBoxes', $checkedBoxes.length);
  $checkedBoxes.each(function(i, e) {
    checked_values.push($(e).val());
  });
  alert(checked_values);
};

$('button').click(findChecked);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<label><input type="checkbox" checked value="1" /> 1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="2" /> 2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="3" /> 3</label>
<button>See checked</button>
```